# How to determine a unique header pattern for custom communication protocol?

Tags: network-protocols

I am creating a protocol to transmit data over a serial link. Is there a mathematical way to make sure the header pattern is unique and is not repeated in the payload region? Or do I have to manually compare it with all the payload bit patterns?

I am still designing the frame. Its size is approximately 192 bits. Bits can be lost in between during communication, hence can't rely on size. Frames are transmitted back to back with no time gap in between.

Any books, articles, references etc would help.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to use the header as a separation between some kind of records? Otherwise, why does the header need not to be repeated in the payload? Everything that follows the header is payload.

Comment: The frames will be transmitted back to back, with no time gaps in between 2 frames. A header pattern in the payload region will trigger a new frame detection from a wrong position. So a unique header will prevent this.

Comment: Handling lost bits seems more difficult than bit errors (0 received instead of 1, for example), because most error detection and error correction methods work on bit errors and not on lost bits. What serial link do you use that produces lost bits instead of bit errors?

Answer (score 0):

[8b10b encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8b/10b_encoding) has comma symbols. These comma symbols have bit patterns that don't match any possible payload bit patterns, so they can be used for synchronization.